# SharePoint 2013 Workflows - assign task and get task fields from current Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-tasks-list, task-assignment

I have a workflow of SharePoint 2013 and I need to generate a workflow task to assign to a specific user, this user must enter information in a field of the task list, before approving or rejecting this task.

How can I get that field of the task list from the current workflow?

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a variable to store your Task Field Value.
- Set this variable to a Task Field Value from the `Association Task List` based on the `Task ID` as shown below

  ```
    Set Variable: Value In Associated Task List to Association: Task List:Due Date
  ```

[image]

Comment: How do I get the tasks id from the created task process? I am only able to save the outcome to a variable, not the task id.

Comment: Okay,  I have now got it working using Field "Instace ID" with Value "Workflow Conext:Instance ID".

Comment: @janw Exactly from the instance context of workflow, please if the above answer helped you don't forget to upvote it :)

Comment: "Workflow Conext:Instance ID" is a GUID, it does not work with me. can anyone help please

Comment: We can't compare a GUID with an simple ID. is there something i'm missing ??